# Binary Upload WCF corrupt .mov File

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-data-services, fiddler

I am trying to Upload video File .mov to remote web service from my Fiddle Debugger to test the service but the File stored on the disk comes out to be corrupt? Any suggestions?

Request Headers

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:2487
Content-Length: 2113228
```

Request body

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="IMG_0888.MOV"; filename="IMG_0888.MOV"
Content-Type: video/quicktime

<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\Amrit\Desktop\IMG_0888.MOV*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

C# Code

```
     FileStream fs = null;
            string UniqueId = this.GenerateUID();
            _fileDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(Constants._VideosDirectory,author_id);
            if (!Directory.Exists(_fileDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(_fileDirectory);
            }
            string file = Path.Combine(_fileDirectory, "test.mov");
  //        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, request.FileName);

            try
            {
                using (FileStream targetStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create,
                                 FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    //read from the input stream in 65000 byte chunks

                    const int bufferLen = 65000;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                    int count = 0;
                    while ((count = request.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                    {
                        // save to output stream
                        targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    targetStream.Close();
                    return "done";
                    //sourceStream.Close();
                }
            }


            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "fail";
            }
            finally
            {

            }
```

Comment: could well be because you're saving the whole request to disk - you need to fish into the request and get the actual file contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andras points out, you might be saving the whole request to disk and not just the content, but more likely is that you're saving the unicode byte order mark (BOM) to the start of the file (which is done automatically by some of the .NET streams).

First thing you should do is check the length of the saved file to the length of the original, the new file is likely going to be ~3 bytes longer in lenght, this indicates that a BOM has been addded.

To confirm, open both the files in a hex editor and look to see what the content looks like, then compare this to what your source file is. When comparing the two hex files you should only look at the first few characters and the last few (if the last are different that means your stream isn't completing and your file is truncated, if the first are different that means you have a BOM attached).

What you likely need to use is `File.WriteBytes` instead of the `FileStream` this will prevent the BOM from being included.

Comment: Thanks @Seph that worked for me , I HTTP parse the Stream and got the FileContents as Bytes and used File.WriteBytes

Comment: How would you remove the header from the stream? I am having this issue where I upload a .zip and it saves the file with the http headers in it.